# How can I join all the JSON into one using Java on Apache beam, considering it works in parallel?

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-beam

I have a JSON structure that is formatted like this

```json
{"companyId":"xxxx", "asOfDate":"2022-12-11T00:00:00", "data":[{"demographicVariable":"Ethnicity", "value": "23" }]}

{"companyId":"xxxx", "asOfDate":"2022-12-11T00:00:00", "data":[{"demographicVariable":"Age Band", "value": 10}]}
```

How can I join all the JSON into one using Java on Apache beam, considering it works in parallel?

The result should be:

```json
{"companyId":"xxxx", "asOfDate":"2022-12-11T00:00:00", "data":[{"demographicVariable":"Age Band", "value": 10},{"demographicVariable":"Ethnicity", "value": "23" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to convert common elements to a [key-value pair](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/KV.html) (e.g., KV<String, Demographics>) and apply a [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/aggregation/groupbykey/).

After a GroupByKey operation you will have a key-value pair of your key, and an Iterable of the Demographics. You should be able to write a [ParDo/DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/pardo/) that will convert that to a JSON.

Please note that depending on the size of the data or group, there are parallelism concerns. The entire group will be processed by a single worker.

If using streaming, you will need to use the concept of windows and triggers to define the behavior of your pipeline. Please check [Beam Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonToRow](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/JsonToRow.java) transform to convert your Json into Beam rows and then leverage all [Beam Schema transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#662-schema-transforms), like Group, Join, etc